# How to make a triangle on top of the UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

How can a make a triangle on top of the `UIView` as a anchor to a `UIButton`, like in the picture below? I want the triangle to change the position when the other Button is selected. Please only answers written in swift. :)

[image]

Comment: Downgrading is ok. But if you do not leave a comment, @telip007 cannot improve his question.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot displays a *popover*. Use a UIPopoverController and you'll get the triangle automatically.

Comment: I don't think he can use popover on iPhone

Comment: Oh ok thank u Matt and Nikita is this sarcasm or why I can't use popover on an iPhone ?

Comment: I will try this solution first and tell u later if it worked :)

Comment: @NikitaZernov Well, you can think that, but you are wrong. Popover has been available on iPhone since iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes solutions are simpler then expected. Just draw all three triangles in storyboard. Then in your UIController you use the `hidden` flag to show or hide the triangle.

Comment: Ok could u tell me how ? :)